# JSON parsing in ajax , php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to parse JSON, but it gives the wrong result.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]');

alert(obj);
```

Please check the code and provide me any suggestion.

Comment: you cannot alert object use console.log(obj);

Comment: There is nothing wrong, you are parsing an array. Open the console of your browser and try: var obj = JSON.parse('[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]'); obj[0];  // this will print an object.

Comment: "it gives the wrong result" — It gives the result I'd expect it to give. What result do you expect it to give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not `alert()` objects. So Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

By The Way you can `alert()` individual values.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]');
console.log(obj);

alert(obj[0].name); // you can alert values
alert(obj[0].age);  // you can alert values
alert(obj[0].city); // you can alert values
```

Comment: Thanks for this valuable answer, I have one more question, can i ask?

Comment: @AshishRana  yes you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

### You can also use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to parse json string

```js
var test = '[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]';
var obj = eval ("(" + test + ")");

console.log(obj);
//console.log(obj[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     You have an array in json object you can get the json object
     values by referencing the key name.

     alert(obj[0].name);
     alert the value of json object at 0 index and by providing the key name.

 <script>
 var obj = JSON.parse('[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]');
 alert(obj);

   alert(obj[0].name);
  </script>
```